# How to correctly restore directory backed up with duplicity

Tags: backup, duplicity

When I backup a directory with duplicity, I can only restore the contents from within directory, but not the whole directory itself. Here is what I have.

I have a folder to backup: `/var/www/wordpress`, and it's content is:

```
root@virtualbox:~# ls /var/www/wordpress/
index.php        wp-admin              wp-content         wp-load.php      wp-signup.php
license.txt      wp-blog-header.php    wp-cron.php        wp-login.php     wp-trackback.php
readme.html      wp-comments-post.php  wp-includes        wp-mail.php      xmlrpc.php
wp-activate.php  wp-config-sample.php  wp-links-opml.php  wp-settings.php
```

I back it up in the following way:

```
duplicity full -v2 --no-encryption /var/www/wordpress/ rsync://user@example.com//backup/worpdress
```

However when I try to restore it with:

```
duplicity restore --no-encryption --file-to-restore wordpress rsync://user@example.com//backups/wordpress /var/www/wordpress
```

I get an error `wordpress not found in archive - no files restored.`. If I list the content in my backups with duplicity, I get:

```
$ duplicity list-current-files --time 1M rsync://user@example.com//backups/wordpress
Sun Oct 15 21:43:48 2017 wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-rss.php
Sun Oct 15 21:43:48 2017 wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-search.php
Sun Oct 15 21:43:48 2017 wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-tag-cloud.php
...
```

that is, all files are there, but the top lever directory `wordpress/` is not present as the root of the relative path of backed up files. **How can I backup whole directory so that it is included in the output of the `list-current-files` and that I can use it in `restore` action?**

Also, I know that I can backup whole folder (folder included) if I reformat my command as:

```
duplicity full -v3 --no-encryption --include '/var/www/wordpress/' --exclude '**' / rsync://root@206.189.58.15//backups/w4
```

Then I get in the list output:

```
Sun Oct 15 21:43:48 2017 var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-rss.php
Sun Oct 15 21:43:48 2017 var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-search.php
Sun Oct 15 21:43:48 2017 var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-tag-cloud.php
```

...

But is this the only way (I don't won't the whole path `/var/www` backed up)? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there.

Try using

```
duplicity full -v3 --no-encryption --include '/var/www/wordpress/' --exclude '**' /var/www/ rsync://root@206.189.58.15//backups/w4
```

This will include the /wordpress directory, but leaving out everything else  in /var/www/.